# How to serialize QSound?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, wav

I'm looking for a way to store some *.wav sounds persistently.

In my application I'm already serializing several things into a little binary database using *boost*. Now I'm trying to store QSounds in this database, too, which if obviously not working. I don't want to deliver the wav-files to the exe, but rather have them compiled into the exe or in a separate data file.

Is there any way to serialize a QSound or should I try another way?

- Is there an alternative for handling wav-files with C++ or Qt?
- Is there any way at all to store and restore those files without having them lying around as wav-files?

I'm often using boost serialization so my first thought was to use it for those files too. Maybe someone can give me a hint on what I should have a look at.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[QSound](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qsound.html) is a simple class for playing sound, not for "sound objects" (a little unfortunate naming in my opinion).

You can use [Qt resources](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/resources.html) to store your files inside your exe.

Comment: Is *Qt resources* able to handle *.wav files?

Comment: @Exa: Yes it is. You can store any files as resources.

Comment: Yes, you can store anything in it.

Comment: @Exa yes, you can store them but you can't play them from Qt resources with QSound, they have to be in regular files. Phonon and QAudioOutput  can play files from resources.

Comment: Yeah, I'm using MediaObject and audioOutput from Phonon now.

Answer (score 2):

`QSound` is relatively primitive. The [Qt Phonon](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/phonon-overview.html) module is has much more features.

You should look at the [`MediaObject`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/phonon-mediaobject.html) class (can take a byte array as input), or possible the `MediaSource` class (implement a custom `QIODevice` on top of your serialization API).

Phonon's a big module though, might not be appropriate for your use-case.

Another option would be the `QtMultimedia` module, and the [`QAudioOuput`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qaudiooutput.html) class, that can also take a `QIODevice` as a data source.